# How to properly set custom long click listener?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to set my own long click listener on Unlock button. Whenever I press the Unlock button it summarize duration and I can unlock permanently clicking.

```
Unlock.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Unlock.setText("Press to unlock");
                        isLongPress = true;
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (isLongPress) {
                                    Unlock();
                                }
                            }
                        }, longClickDuration); //amount of time of long click
                    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Unlock.setText("Unlock");
                        isLongPress = false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use timer and get current system time, and match specific time in runnable thread. to some thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just handle long clicks consider using the following code:

```
        Unlock.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                your code
            }
        });
```

But if the `Unlock();` should be invoked after a certain (customizable) amount of time, you should measure this time in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` handler. As @Attaullah Khan said, use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` system timer to correctly count number of milliseconds at two moments (when button was pressed and released) and if the time is greater than `longClickDuration` then invoke `Unlock`

The `handler.postDelayed` that you call in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` handler just invokes a check of pressed state after `longClickDuration` interval and if your button gets suddenly pressed at that moment, the verification passes that is not correct